# Similarity of Objects based on multiple variables

Tags: sorting, equality

I am working on a Simple hypothetical Allocation Problem. I have some Virtual Machines(VM) placed on a Physical Machine (PM). The VMs and PMs have 3 common variables, CPU, Memory, Network. The VMs require these resources, while PMs can provide these resources.

At certain points I need to check if the VM is similar to (or larger than) other VM or a PM.

I need to score them so they can be easily sorted. A naive way (probably wrong way), I am doing it right now is, to divide the requirements and if all the ratios are less than or equal to 1, I will assign a score by multiplying all the three ratios. E.g.:

VM1 : 100CPU, 200Mem, 50Net;

PM1 : 200CPU, 300Mem, 50Net;

The total Score will be 0.5 * 0.67 * 1 = 0.335.
This works, as I am able to sort them in descending order of their total score.

But If I want to compare that two VMs equal to another VM, I cannot use this score. For Example:

VM1 : 100 CPU, 200 Mem, 50 Net;

VM2 : 100 CPU, 200 Mem, 50 Net;

VM3 : 200 CPU, 400 Mem, 100 Net;

The score of VM1 and VM2 w.r.t to VM3 will be 0.5 * 0.5, 0.5 = 0.125
If I add both the score I will only get 0.250, in fact combined, they are equal to the specs of VM3.

I am not sure the type of problem I am facing here, and some initial goolging didnt helped in identifying the problem as well.

My Question is, Is there any standard way to compare objects with different properties which have different units? so that they can also be ranked?